# raspberry pi, ffmpeg, libmp3lame stream to icecast2 fails with: av_interleaved_write_frame(): Connection reset by peer

Tags: ffmpeg, mp3, audio-streaming, raspberry-pi2, icecast

finally, i want to merge or mix audio channels from two streams into one new audio stream. but at first i want to relay or reencode an existing stream from an icecast2 server - and send it back to the icecast as new mountpoint. this stream comes from mpd on the same raspberry pi 2. and it works fine.

i've got lame and ffmpeg on this way:

```
cd /usr/src
git clone https://github.com/rbrito/lame
cd lame
sudo ./configure
sudo make
sudo make install
```

then ffmpeg

```
cd /usr/src
sudo rm -R ffmpeg
git clone git://source.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.git
cd ffmpeg
sudo ./configure --arch=armel --target-os=linux --enable-gpl --enable-libmp3lame --enable-nonfree
sudo make
sudo make install
```

A simple test fails with:

```
**av_interleaved_write_frame(): Connection reset by peer
Error writing trailer of icecast://admin:hackme@127.0.0.1:8000/listen: Connection reset by peersize=       5kB time=00:00:00.28 bitrate= 144.7kbits/s speed=1.73x**
```

(with strange spaces)

The reencoding ffmpeg script:

```
ffmpeg \
 -i http://127.0.0.1:8000/live \
 -c:a libmp3lame -b:a 128k \
 -legacy_icecast 1 \
 -content_type audio/mpeg \
 -ice_name "hack radio" \
 -f mp3 icecast://admin:hackme@127.0.0.1:8000/listen \
 -y \
 -stats \
 -report
```

I tried legacy_icecast 1 or 0.

The ffmpeg report:

```
ffmpeg started on 2016-04-09 at 00:57:56
Report written to "ffmpeg-20160409-005756.log"
Command line:
ffmpeg -i http://127.0.0.1:8000/live -muxpreload 10 -c:a libmp3lame -b:a 128k -legacy_icecast 1 -content_type audio/mpeg -ice_name "NFS One Radio" -f mp3 icecast://admin:hackme@127.0.0.1:8000/listen -y -stats -report
ffmpeg version N-79262-gae8a13c Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.6 (Debian 4.6.3-14+rpi1)
  configuration: --arch=armel --target-os=linux --enable-gpl --enable-libmp3lame --enable-nonfree
  libavutil      55. 20.100 / 55. 20.100
  libavcodec     57. 34.100 / 57. 34.100
  libavformat    57. 31.100 / 57. 31.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
  libavfilter     6. 41.100 /  6. 41.100
  libswscale      4.  1.100 /  4.  1.100
  libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Splitting the commandline.
Reading option '-i' ... matched as input file with argument 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/live'.
Reading option '-muxpreload' ... matched as option 'muxpreload' (set the initial demux-decode delay) with argument '10'.
Reading option '-c:a' ... matched as option 'c' (codec name) with argument 'libmp3lame'.
Reading option '-b:a' ... matched as option 'b' (video bitrate (please use -b:v)) with argument '128k'.
Reading option '-legacy_icecast' ... matched as AVOption 'legacy_icecast' with argument '1'.
Reading option '-content_type' ... matched as AVOption 'content_type' with argument 'audio/mpeg'.
Reading option '-ice_name' ... matched as AVOption 'ice_name' with argument 'NFS One Radio'.
Reading option '-f' ... matched as option 'f' (force format) with argument 'mp3'.
Reading option 'icecast://admin:hackme@127.0.0.1:8000/listen' ... matched as output file.
Reading option '-y' ... matched as option 'y' (overwrite output files) with argument '1'.
Reading option '-stats' ... matched as option 'stats' (print progress report during encoding) with argument '1'.
Reading option '-report' ... matched as option 'report' (generate a report) with argument '1'.
Finished splitting the commandline.
Parsing a group of options: global .
Applying option y (overwrite output files) with argument 1.
Applying option stats (print progress report during encoding) with argument 1.
Applying option report (generate a report) with argument 1.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Parsing a group of options: input file http://127.0.0.1:8000/live.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an input file: http://127.0.0.1:8000/live.
[http @ 0x343cee0] Setting default whitelist 'http,https,tls,rtp,tcp,udp,crypto,httpproxy'
[http @ 0x343cee0] request: GET /live HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Lavf/57.31.100
Accept: */*
Range: bytes=0-
Connection: close
Host: 127.0.0.1:8000
Icy-MetaData: 1


[mp3 @ 0x343c7e0] Format mp3 probed with size=262144 and score=50
[mp3 @ 0x343c7e0] Skipping 656 bytes of junk at 0.
[mp3 @ 0x343c7e0] Before avformat_find_stream_info() pos: 656 bytes read:272000 seeks:0
[mp3 @ 0x343c7e0] All info found
[mp3 @ 0x343c7e0] After avformat_find_stream_info() pos: 42640 bytes read:272000 seeks:0 frames:50
Input #0, mp3, from 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/live':
  Metadata:
    icy-br          : 256
    icy-name        : NFS One Radio
    icy-pub         : 0
    StreamTitle     : x
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 256 kb/s
    Stream #0:0, 50, 1/14112000: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 256 kb/s
Successfully opened the file.
Parsing a group of options: output file icecast://admin:hackme@127.0.0.1:8000/listen.
Applying option muxpreload (set the initial demux-decode delay) with argument 10.
Applying option c:a (codec name) with argument libmp3lame.
Applying option b:a (video bitrate (please use -b:v)) with argument 128k.
Applying option f (force format) with argument mp3.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an output file: icecast://admin:hackme@127.0.0.1:8000/listen.
[icecast @ 0x34492c0] No default whitelist set
[http @ 0x344b9e0] Setting default whitelist 'http,https,tls,rtp,tcp,udp,crypto,httpproxy'
[http @ 0x344b9e0] request: SOURCE /listen HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Lavf/57.31.100
Accept: */*
Connection: close
Host: 127.0.0.1:8000
Content-Type: audio/mpeg
Icy-MetaData: 1
Ice-Name: NFS One Radio
Ice-Public: 0
Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46bWFyc2Jhc2U=
```

The Output from ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg started on 2016-04-09 at 01:06:46
Report written to "ffmpeg-20160409-010646.log"
ffmpeg version N-79262-gae8a13c Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.6 (Debian 4.6.3-14+rpi1)
  configuration: --arch=armel --target-os=linux --enable-gpl --enable-libmp3lame --enable-nonfree
  libavutil      55. 20.100 / 55. 20.100
  libavcodec     57. 34.100 / 57. 34.100
  libavformat    57. 31.100 / 57. 31.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
  libavfilter     6. 41.100 /  6. 41.100
  libswscale      4.  1.100 /  4.  1.100
  libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
[mp3 @ 0x25ec7e0] Skipping 501 bytes of junk at 0.
Input #0, mp3, from 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/live':
  Metadata:
    icy-br          : 256
    icy-name        : NFS One Radio
    icy-pub         : 0
    StreamTitle     : x
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 256 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 256 kb/s
Output #0, mp3, to 'icecast://admin:hackme@127.0.0.1:8000/listen':
  Metadata:
    icy-br          : 256
    icy-name        : NFS One Radio
    icy-pub         : 0
    StreamTitle     : x
    TSSE            : Lavf57.31.100
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3 (libmp3lame), 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 128 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.34.100 libmp3lame
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mp3 (native) -> mp3 (libmp3lame))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Connection reset by peer
Error writing trailer of icecast://admin:hackme@127.0.0.1:8000/listen: Connection reset by peersize=      16kB time=00:00:00.96 bitrate= 132.9kbits/s speed=3.14x
video:0kB audio:16kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 1.183730%
```

The icecast works fine with mpd. And icecast creates a new mountpoint when feeded.

For some reason the connection to the icecast drops. Ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Check the icecast error.log, also verify that you can reach the Icecast server otherwise, e.g. with a web browser or just "curl -v http://127.0.0.1:8000/ >/dev/null".

Comment: ahja... the error.log said:
[2016-04-09  10:18:36] INFO connection/_handle_source_request Source logging in at mountpoint "/listen"


[2016-04-09  10:18:36] INFO connection/_handle_source_request Source (/listen) attempted to login with invalid or missing password

Comment: set the user and password to the source... then it works. wtf.

Comment: yes, '**admin**' is not allowed to stream. the global source user "*source*" can log into every mountpoint using the '**source-password**'.